# I am trying to make a JFrame that displays a list of elements each representing a file in a directory

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner, defaultlistmodel

Okay so I am making a software that pulls user information from a folder of text files. Each text file has 2 lines. The first/last name and the phone number. I am making code that opens up a JFrame that displays a list of all the users in the folder. I wrote some code and tried troubleshooting it but I have no idea why it isn't working. I think it's a GUI thing but i've looked through so many java docs examples, I can't see what I did wrong.

I have my code in this method:

```
public void createDir() {
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setVisible(true);
f.setSize(600,400);
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setTitle("User Directory");

DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(listModel);

File directory = new File("Z:\\Documents\\users");
File[] listOfUsers = directory.listFiles(); // returns a file array of all txt files in the user folder

String n = null;
String p = null;
Scanner s;
for (File file : listOfUsers) // runs for each file in the listOfUsers file array, replacing 'file' with the current userfile
{
    if (file.isFile()) // if the item selected is a file
    {
        try
        {
            s = new Scanner(file); // creates a scanner to read the current user file
            int i = 0; // sets the counter that is used to read name and phone number associated with the file

            while(s.hasNextLine()) // reads the file using the counter to obtain the name and phone number, storing each in the 'n' and 'p' variables
            {   
                if(i==0)
                    n = s.nextLine();
                if(i==1)
                    p = s.nextLine();
                                i++;
            }

        listModel.addElement(n + " " + p); // the user shows up on the list item as "First Last ###-###-####"
        s.close(); // closes the scanner for re-use

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) // incase of exception thrown
        {
            System.out.print("exception occured: " + e);
        }               
    }
}

    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
    list.setSelectedIndex(0);
    JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list); // creates a scrollpane for the JList component 'list'

    JPanel dirPanel = new JPanel();
    f.add(dirPanel);
    dirPanel.add(listScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER); // adds the component
}
```

Whenever the method is called, the JFrame appears but the entire window is black except for a small white sliver in the corner. At that point, I can't close it and it is frozen. And if you're thinking that it isn't closing because f.setDefaultCloseOperation() isn't called, it's because this is a method that is called by the actionListener of a button on the MAIN program. I get no error message and I have no idea what I should do. The entire program freezes up and becomes uncloseable.

Comment: What isn't working? If there is an error, please add it to your original post.

Comment: Can you add temporary `System.out.println`s in different check point places like in the beginning of body of for loop or inside if statement or in scanner while loop?

Comment: rsutormin that's a great idea. That will atleast help me narrow it down.

Comment: You might have an infinite loop somewhere, check for one.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Reading all the files in the user's directory is going to be a time consuming process, reading all the files isn't exactly going to be fast either

Answer (score 1):

Having tested your code, you have a potential infinite loop.

```
while(s.hasNextLine()) // reads the file using the counter to obtain the name and phone number, storing each in the 'n' and 'p' variables
{   
    if(i==0)
        n = s.nextLine();
    if(i==1)
        p = s.nextLine();
    i++;
}
```

Basically, here, if the file actually has more then two lines, you loop will never exit, because you basically ignore any other lines

So, instead, either you need to ignore anything after the second line and `break` out of the loop or you need to throw an `Exception` so you know which files are giving your problems...

```
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(file)) {
    int i = 0; // sets the counter that is used to read name and phone number associated with the file

try (Scanner s = new Scanner(file)) {
    int i = 0; // sets the counter that is used to read name and phone number associated with the file

    while (s.hasNextLine()) // reads the file using the counter to obtain the name and phone number, storing each in the 'n' and 'p' variables
    {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                n = s.nextLine();
                break;
            case 1:
                p = s.nextLine();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IOException("Invalid file format, more then two lines have been found!");
        }
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    listModel.addElement(n + " " + p); // the user shows up on the list item as "First Last ###-###-####"

} catch (IOException e) // incase of exception thrown
{
    System.out.print("exception occured: " + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also, as has already been noted, you should be calling `setVisible` last, after you have created the UI.

Have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details about the `try (Scanner s = new Scanner(file)) {` line

Answer (score 0):

Put f.setVisible(true) after add components to JFrame. i.e in the last line rather than the second

Comment: After I do that, the frame doesn't show up at all. That makes me think that the program is freezing when it's fetching the data from the files. Your suggestion actually helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: And before i++ put else statement to read next line. Cause if there is a file contains more than two lines the while loop will run for ever

Comment: Ibraheem you were spot on. I've created a boolean that is declared as true RIGHT before the while loop and put it in the loop. By adding "if(i==2) boolean = false;" I was able to end the loop and keep the program going. Thanks guy!